# Issue while connecting as sqlplus system/system@orcl

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am facing an issue while connecting through command prompt as `sqlplus system/system@orcl` and it is giving me an error saying

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0 .
```

I did googling and found same issues and followed the steps given by them but still unable to resolve it. Sugeest me solution.

Comment: Check whether database is being shutdown or not?

Comment: actually i am receiving this error  C:\Users\mkhatal>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jun 26 12:52:21 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:

Comment: So your error is basically `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error` ?

Comment: If you are getting `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`, then try do a `tnsping orcl` and if it fails check whether your database is up and running.

Comment: it doesn't get failed!!

Comment: shutdown your database and start it again. You could use shutdown immediate to force a shutdown.

Comment: when i try to connect it is giving me error,after connecting as /nolog. Error is SQL> connect sys/sys as sysdba;
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the alert log for any messages. Maybe this gives you a clue.

```
> cd $ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/alert
> tail -n 100 log.xml
```

If this doesn't help, then you can shutdown the system. Below you will find my emergency shutdown procedure (for Unix / Linux). In a production system I suggest to do some more investigations before you follow this procedure. For test or development system it worked very well in the past.

Logion as sysdba

```
> sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Try to shutdown Immediate. This may take some time, because uncommited transactions are rolled back.

```
SQL> shutdown immediate 

Expected output: 
Database closed. 
Database dismounted. 
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

If this doesn't help, then shutdown abort. 
The 2nd shutdown makes sure, the stopped database is in a clean state!

```
SQL> shutdown abort 
SQL> startup restrict
SQL> shutdown immediate
```

If this doesn't work, pmon has to be killed. This will stop the database immedietely

```
> ps -ef | grep pmon 
... 
> kill -9 <pid> 
> sqlplus / as sysdba 
SQL> startup restrict 
SQL> shutdown immediate
```

Startup the system

```
SQL> startup
```

Comment: stated giving error while executing below statement: C:\Users\mkhatal>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jun 26 12:52:21 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:

Comment: Assuming, you have installed your database as Unix user oracle, then you have log in as user oracle to your database server.